# Vuforia marker based AR

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, android-augmented-reality

I have been using Unity 2022.3.6f1 and vuforia 10.17 for developing AR of civil infrastructures such as pipelines, manholes. I am using image-based marker for tracking and instantiating 3D objects. I am using Android smartphone. I am facing a trouble while running my AR application.

Problem: Even though extended tracking is enabled, the model drifts or moves along with the user, when user moves from one position to another.

Marker size: 20cm X 20cm
3D model size: approximately 16m x 20m

I have tried the same model using ground plane (markerless) option. Still the object drifts while running the AR application.

Does anyone have faced this issue; can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Sounds like it could be related to ARCore support, as Vuforia Engine Extended Tracking feature is enabled by it. Can you confirm that the device supports ARCore? And that the are ARCore app (Google Play Services for AR) is installed on the device?